# Can gdb use the Symbol information like IDA after dealed with Clutch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gdb, jailbreak, encryption

I use [Clutch](https://github.com/KJCracks/Clutch) to remove encryption of ipa, and then I use gdb and lldb to detach that program, but it seems the debuggers were not using the symbol like IDA / Hopper Disassembler / class-dump-z. Is this possible? or just my gdb version is not well enough?

gdb version
 [image]

gdb loading info
[image]

Maybe something like [SymTabCreator](https://github.com/karstenBriksoft/SymTabCreator), but for iOS?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @EmployedRussian Is this possible to use the Symbol and how??

Comment: I finally find a solution which may work, 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554070/import-class-dump-info-into-gdb