# Import class-dump info into LLDB

Tags: objective-c, lldb, debug-symbols

This question is basically a clone of [Import class-dump info into GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554070/import-class-dump-info-into-gdb), but with LLDB instead of GDB.

---

Using the method described in the answer to the question mentioned above, I am able to create symbol file containing the symbols called `test.stabs`.

To import and use this info in LLDB, I tried to do the following:

```
$ lldb test
(lldb) target module add test.stabs
(lldb) b +[TestClass randomNum]
Breakpoint 1: where = test.stabs`+[TestClass randomNum]:F(0,1), address = 0x0000000100000ed0
```

As you can see LLDB can load the address, but when actually running the target, LLDB doesn't break:

```
(lldb) r
Process 40430 launched: '/Users/Tyilo/test' (x86_64)
num: 4
Process 40430 exited with status = 0 (0x00000000)
```

You could of course specify the address of the breakpoint directly:

```
(lldb) b -a 0x0000000100000ed0
```

and it will work.

Is there a way of making the breakpoint sat by `b +[TestClass randomNum]` work in LLDB?

Comment: Frankly, if LLDB isn't already making use of valuable information in the binary, that's a bug that should be filed against LLDB. There should be no reason to "teach" LLDB about things that class-dump obtained from the binary.

Answer (score 4):

I've made a python function that can be used to achieve what I want, however it only works if the program is running. Save the code below as `break_message.py` and import it into lldb by running `command script import break_message.py`. Now you can use it like so:

```
$ lldb -p $(pgrep Finder)
(lldb) command script import break_message.py
(lldb) break_message -[TApplicationController cmdEmptyTrash:]
(lldb) continue
```

Now open your Trash in Finder and empty it (put something in it if it's already empty). The breakpoint will be hit in lldb.

---

```
import lldb
import re

def lldb_run(command):
    res = lldb.SBCommandReturnObject()
    lldb.debugger.GetCommandInterpreter().HandleCommand(command, res)
    return res

def lldb_call(command):
    res = lldb_run('call ' + command)
    out = res.GetOutput()
    r = re.compile(r'^[^=]*= (.*)\n$')
    m = r.search(out)
    return m.groups()[0]

def __lldb_init_module(debugger, internal_dict):
    lldb_run('command script add -f break_message.{0} {0}'.format('break_message'))

def break_message(debugger, command, result, internal_dict):
    r = re.compile(r'([+-])\s*\[\s*(\S+)\s+([^\]]+)\]')
    m = r.search(command)
    if not m:
        print 'Error in message format!'
        return

    typ, cls, sel = m.groups()
    sel = re.sub(r'\s+', '', sel)

    meta = typ == '+'

    clsptr = lldb_call('(id)objc_getClass("{}")'.format(cls))
    if clsptr == 'nil':
        print "Couldn't find class: " + cls
        return

    selptr = lldb_call('(id)sel_registerName("{}")'.format(sel))
    if selptr == 'nil':
        print "Couldn't register selector: " + sel
        return

    func = 'class_getClassMethod' if meta else 'class_getInstanceMethod'
    method = lldb_call('(id){}({}, {})'.format(func, clsptr, selptr))
    if method == 'nil':
        print "Couldn't find method for: " + sel
        return

    imp = lldb_call('(id)method_getImplementation({})'.format(method))

    lldb_run('breakpoint set -a {}'.format(imp))
```

Answer (score 1):

lldb thinks the name of your method is `+[TestClass randomNum]:F(0,1)`?  The name of your file, `test.stabs`, makes me think that it has been constructed with stabs debug info -- that looks like stabs.

lldb doesn't know anything about the stabs debug format -- and you can't even generate it with clang -- we use DWARF for everything on Mac OS X and iOS.  You would probably have more success stripping the stabs debug info out of your binary entirely (see the `strip(1)`) command - lldb wouldn't be distracted by it then.

Comment: Despite the name `test.stabs`, the file is actually an empty dylib with symbols pointing to the addresses in the stripped executable.